# Grab the HREF and discard of that original <a> tag with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, href, strip-tags

Im working with wordpress and this function im using returns this or something that looks like this:

```
<li><a href="http://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/picture.png">picture</a></li>
```

What Im trying to do is get the HREF from that tag and store it in a variable, so I can manipulate it easily. Then after i have the HREF info i want to discard of the `<li>` and the `<a>` tag.

I looked into the php function `strip_tag()` and that doesn't do what i want.

If this is overly complicated i will just not include the work in the webpage, but if it can be done.. help would be great.

Comment: Can you please provide the two values you want afterwards? Can't tell if you want to include quotes, href, link destination, etc.

Comment: oh I just want the this information: http://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/picture.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure no other function exists that returns the unformatted data.

If not, here's a quick and dirty regex to pull out the URL:

```
$str = '<li><a href="http://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/picture.png">picture</a></li>';

preg_match('~\shref="([^"]++)"~', $str, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
```

Comment: i have already checked on any available functions and none return it unformatted. That is actually as unformatted as i can get it with the functions settings i have in place.

Comment: @ApoY2k: `++` is a possessive quantifier. Just a minor optimization to prevent possible useless backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will look something like this.

```
preg_match('@<a href="(.*?)"@i', $your_string_here, $matches);
$the_url = $matches[1];
```

More examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

How about something more hands on? - http://wp-snippets.com/727/custom-display-of-links-blogroll/

```
    $links = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->links ORDER BY link_name ASC");
    //start going through all the links and get the required values for each link
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      $linkurl=$link->link_url;
      $linkdesc=$link->link_description;
      $linkname=$link->link_name;
      $linkimage=$link->link_image;
      $linknotes=$link->link_notes; }
```

Wordpress has many built in functions. You can probably get the image URL itself without having to hack it out of the code.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

This will return the url if you know the attachment id

```
$imgData = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id);
echo $imgData[0];
```

Comment: the reason why i cant use any other function is because im making use of the LINK section that i never seem to use. So im using it as a simple way for the end-user to change a link/picture without knowing code. the only function that works with the LINK section is the wp_list_bookmarks()

Comment: How about something that gives you more direct access? Updated my answer.